# RTC workspace folder creation

Tags: rtc, jazz

I am getting an error while creating repository workspace folder.

It is taking only one  folder path in advance setting and when I am creating workspace in some other folder, it does not create it.

How would you resolve this?

Comment: Could you add some more details about your environment and the specific error?  This question is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is taking only one folder path in advance setting

That means you are no longer in the "repo workspace creation" step: you have created it (and you should see it in the "my repository workspaces" section).
You create loading your repo workspace into a local workspace or sandbox. That is the step which requires to specify a local folder (on your computer) in the "advanced setting" section.

Simply make sure that the folder (and its full path) you are entering in that setting is:

- not an existing one. For instance: `C:\a\b\c\d` means that d must not exist yet: RTC will create it when loading the sandbox. `C:\a\b\c` must exist.
- isn't in folder already used as a sandbox: if you see a `.jazz5` folder in any of the parent folder you want, meaning in the aforementioned example in `C:\a`, `C:\a\b` or `C:\a\b\c`, you cannot use those parent folders to load a sandbox in `d`.
  A sandbox is a folder with a `.jazz5` in it (local cache), and you cannot nest sandboxes.

Comment: I have a .jazz5 folder in parent folder so the problem is obvious.
However I cannot seem to remove the folder, it keeps reappearing (after refresh) when I delete it locally. It is probably due old sandboxes that got deleted wrongly. How can I delete .jazz5 folder without it reappearing (the old repository workspaces are not found in workspace search) ?